# Convert QImage to ROS image format

Tags: qt, qt-creator, ros

I have a `QImage` in my "Select_Object" node in ROS.

How can I convert this `QImage` to ROS image format, but without using OpenCV?

Comment: What is the ROS image format? Is it monochrome, 8-bit with palette, 16-bit, 24-bit, 32-bit?

Comment: My QImage is in RGB888 format so, i think 24-bit ROS format will work

Comment: @sashoalm Pls suggest how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

`QImage` allows you to set the format, using [QImage::convertToFormat](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qimage.html#convertToFormat-2). Then you can get the raw data using [QImage::constBits](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qimage.html#constBits).

So all you need to do is set the format to something that ROS can use, and then get the raw data.

This is a [list of all the available formats](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qimage.html#Format-enum).

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to do it. My task is to Publish the QImage from the "Select_Object" node so that my another node i.e. "Detect_object" can subscribe it. That's why i want to convert the QImage into ROS format first before publishing it. But i don't understand how to do it after converting QImage format

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with ROS, I'm only familiar with Qt. The answer I gave you should be enough to put you in the right direction, though, just research what encoding sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr has, and I'm sure you'll figure out how to do it. Sorry for asking, but from the way you're asking for additional help I gather you're not very experienced with programming? Or is it just that you're not familiar with Qt/C++/ROS? That would give me an idea of how much help you would need vs. how much can you do on your own.

Comment: Yes i am not that much familiar with programming. I am learning as the new things are coming. And, actually i am able to convert the QImage into cvMat format but my requirement is not to use openCV.

Comment: Can you suggest some method. I am still dealing with the same problem of converting the QImage into sensor_msgs image in ROS

Comment: What does sensor_msgs look like? I.e. its definition in code. Is it a struct?

Comment: although i am not going to use openCv but to get sensor_msgs from cvMat image, i have to do something like this....                      `cv_bridge::CvImage cvi; cvi.header.stamp = time;            
           cvi.header.frame_id = "image";
           cvi.encoding = "bgr8";
           cvi.image = temp;

   sensor_msgs::Image im;   
   cvi.toImageMsg(im);`